# Show custom attribute in sidebar wishlist

Tags: magento-1, custom-options, wishlist

I have a sidebar whislist
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/sidebar.phtml
I need to add a "custom attribute" called manufacturer.

I have tried many options like these but all don't show a thing:

```
<?php echo $this->getManufacturer()) ?>

<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getData('manufacturer')); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getManufacturer() ?>

<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>

<?php echo $item->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?> 
<?php echo $item->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($item); ?>
```

Thisone shows "3" and no manufacturer name, at least showing something..

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getManufacturer()) ?>
```

How can I get my manufacturer there? I can show them about everywhere else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the loop code of sidebar, by default it's:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getWishlistItems() as $_item): ?>
```

Inside thip loop $_item->getManufacturer() will return your attribute value, but you have to be sure, that product have this attribute fulfilled.

You can display it i.e. like this:

```
<?php if ( $_item->getManufacturer() ): ?>
Manufacturer: <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getManufacturer()) ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

**Edit:**

Which Magento version you're using? Probably this code will work, but its not optimal:

```
<?php if ( $manufacturer = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId())->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ): ?>
    Manufacturer: <?php echo $this->htmlEscape( $manufacturer ) ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: This shows the 3 while it should display a manufacturer.
(backend I made a dropdown of the manufacturers)

Comment: Which Magento version you're using?

Probably this code will work, but its not optimal:

`<?php if ( $manufacturer = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId())->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ): ?>
Manufacturer: <?php echo $this->htmlEscape( $manufacturer ) ?>
<?php endif ?>`

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working:

```
<?php echo $item->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>
```

Is likely because `manufacturer` isn't in the `$item`'s parent collection.

You need to extend the method that gets the collection and add the manufacturer attribute from `Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Item_Collection`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve Wishlist Product Items collection
 *
 * @return Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Item_Collection
 */
public function getWishlistItems()
{
    if (is_null($this->_collection)) {
        $this->_collection = clone $this->_createWishlistItemCollection();
        $this->_collection->clear();
        $this->_prepareCollection($this->_collection);
    }
    $this->_collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
    return $this->_collection;
}
```

Comment: I have add the code to /app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Mysql4/Wishlist/Collection.php - It didn't work.

I have add the code to /app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Mysql4/Item/Collection.php - Also didn't work.