# Get product attribute on product/list page

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, product-list

*Magento ver. 1.8.1.0, Ultimo theme*

I'm trying to get product`s attribute according this solution:

[Product Attribute on Products Grid/List View (manufacturer)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5601/product-attribute-on-products-grid-list-view-manufacturer)

### My settings:

[image]

I run following code:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('depths'); ?>
```

Using xDebug I see following:

```
$this->getResource()
```

Resource instantiating well. I have this object

```
        ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
```

[image]

I got my attribute successfully

```
            ->getSource()
```

Before return I have following:

[image]

And on step:

```
                ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
```

When we are getting `$this->getData($attributeCode)` result is NULL and `->getOptionText` also return NULL

I don't know when this attribute should appear in `$this` (read as `$product`) `->getData()` should have this value. If `_data` array have this value why don't I call just on list page `$_product->getData('my_attr')`?

### Could you help me to find the issue?

#### p.s.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getDepths()
```

returns right value

Comment: aaaahhh. Reindex. Now everything is working

Comment: This may help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9928/adding-custom-attributes-to-product-list

Comment: Thank you for your message, I found that problem was in indexes. After reindex the problem was solved